# How to create null SQL parameter for a UniqueIdentifier?

Tags: vb.net

While doing

```
If Me.Id_Padre Is Nothing Then
    comandoSQL.Parameters.Add("@Id_Padre", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = DBNull.Value
Else
    comandoSQL.Parameters.Add("@Id_Padre", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = New Guid(Me.Id_Padre)
End If
```

gives me no error, this instead

```
comandoSQL.Parameters.Add("@Id_Padre", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = IIf(Me.Id_Padre Is Nothing, DbNull.Value, New Guid(Me.Id_Padre))
```

gives me an error saying the value cannot be null.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that Iif will always evaluate (run) both parts. So the last part will throw an exception since Id_Padre is nothing. From documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function):

> IIf always evaluates both truepart and falsepart, even though it
> returns only one of them. Because of this, you should watch for
> undesirable side effects. For example, if evaluating falsepart results
> in a division by zero error, an error occurs even if expr is True.

I recommend using If instead to avoid this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator) so:

```
comandoSQL.Parameters.Add("@Id_Padre", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = If(Me.Id_Padre Is Nothing, DbNull.Value, New Guid(Me.Id_Padre))
```

Comment: Note that the `If` operator was added in VB 2008, so that `IIf` function should not have been used at all for about a decade and a half. It hdd to be used with caution even before that, for the very reason that this question demonstrates. I suspect that, in this case, the OP either meant to type `If` but made a mistake or else misread some example somewhere that actually did use `If`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's been very useful to me. If you'd recommend me any literature on vb.net go ahead.